# Does renderaction calls its corresponding httpPost Action on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm a little new to asp.net mvc and I have a question (very basic). I have hacked around but I am not totally sure about this and I could'nt find anything particularly helpful.

Assume that I have 2 controllers A and B and 2 views FullView and PartView

```
public class AController:...
{
      //Renders FullView
      public ActionResult Create
      {
        ....
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Create
      {
        ....
      }
}


public class BController:...
{
      //Renders an Arbitrary partial View (PartView)
      public ActionResult Create
      {
        ....
      }

      //Saves the data of the partial View
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Create
      {
        ....
      }
}
```

the 1st view (FullView) has the code

```
<%Html.RenderAction("Create", "B"); %>
```

my question is on submit will BController's action ([HttpPost] Create) run?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what action you specify in your `<form />` tag. This doesn't have anything to do with asp.net mvc. If you use `Html.BeginForm()` without parameters it will post to the current url (not the create action on BController).

Answer (score 0):

Well 1st thing you could do is toggle some breakpoints in your actions and hit f5.
Second - what action is called purely depends on what url you hit with what http method.

But for your case, when you post form A and controller A processes post you might get into validation problems and that's when you return View() on a post action and that's why form B is rendered via its post method.

Comment: Hi that is exactly what I did and it did run BControllers post method. But I made some changes and it stopped working. I was surprised that it worked in the 1st place. I just had a (httppost) Create action in my controller (The controller that rendered the partial view) and it broke inside and I was amazed that it ran the code as I was not expecting it but now it's not working and I'm questioning my sanity but I have 1 witness :)